# How to select null image from openfiledialogue

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF app.

I have an image that the user can click on and select a different image to upload.

What I want to be able to do is to allow the user to select 'nothing' or 'null' so that the User can select no image and the existing loaded image will clear.  But, if the user selects 'cancel' I want the existing loaded image to remain.

Can it be done?

My mark-up:

```
<Button Cursor="Hand" ToolTip="Click here to Add logO Image!" x:Name="btnLogo" Style="{DynamicResource NoChromeButton}"  Margin="1,0,0,20" Click="btnLogo_Click">
    <Image x:Name="WORK_SHEET_COMPANY_LOGO" Source="/InformedWorkerClient;component/Images/CompanyLogo.png" Stretch="Fill" Height="74" Width="300"/>
</Button>
```

My code:

```
private void btnLogo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog ofd = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            //either load new image or clear existing one
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       /deal with any errors
    }
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible. I'm not sure if this is even desirable: This would be a very unusual UI and possibly confuse your users. What about adding two buttons instead of one: [Add your logo], [Remove logo]. Or, if you have only space for one button, show *either* [Add your logo] or [Remove logo], depending on whether a logo is currently loaded or not.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion.  I took the idea from using the IDE for .NET where you can select nothing.  Perhaps you are right and it would not be a good idea even if possible  thanks

Answer (score 0):

By what I understand is that you want a user to be able to click something to set the image to nothing. If that is the case, you could always have an image the same color as the form background or what ever you have this picture located at on the form. Then you could just have the image set to that, that way it would look like there is not an image there.

Comment: Hi, I did not down vote. This is similar to what I had in mind but it would still have to be selected by a user and they would have to navigate to that image so not ideal.  so.. i will give yo a +1 to remove the negative for you though :)